# What is wrong is this mysql statement with case?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM PATIENTS A, RECALLS_AFTER_RESERV C
  LEFT JOIN PATIENT_LAST_RESERV D
    ON D.PATIENT_ID = C.PATIENT_ID
 WHERE C.PATIENT_ID = A.ID
   AND C.OFFICE_ID = A.OFFICE_ID
   AND C.OFFICE_ID = ?
   AND YEAR(CONVERT_TZ(C.RECALLS_AT, 'UTC', 'Asia/Tokyo')) = ?
   AND (CASE
          WHEN ISNULL(D.STARTS_AT) THEN
           A.CHECKED_IN_AT
          ELSE
           D.STARTS_AT
       END) >= CONVERT_TZ('2015-01-27 00:00:00', 'Asia/Tokyo', 'UTC')) AND (CASE
   WHEN ISNULL(D.STARTS_AT) THEN
    A.CHECKED_IN_AT
   ELSE
    D.STARTS_AT
END) <= CONVERT_TZ('2015-01-27 23:59:59', 'Asia/Tokyo', 'UTC') AND C.RECALLED_AT IS NULL AND C.STARTS_AT IS NULL
```

I want to use the case to determine whether the D.starts_at have value,if not, I use A.checked_in_at to replace the D.starts_at.but it gives an error

Comment: (1) You should work on formatting your own questions.  (2) You should not use commas in the `where` clause (*always* use explicit `join` syntax).  (3) You should specify the problem that you are having and not make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

(case when isnull(D.starts_at) then A.checked_in_at else D.starts_at end) >= CONVERT_TZ('2015-01-27 00:00:00', 'Asia/Tokyo', 'UTC') )

I finally find the problem, the case statement is right. the problem is the redundant `）`　in the above.